# android GPS current Location null value

Tags: android, gps

i use the following code for getting the current latitude and longitude in services but it always return null. please help me.

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    System.out.println("provider "+provider);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code may be it may help you

```
import com.example.ConfigClass;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GpsListener {

    public static GpsListener refrence = null ;
    public LocationManager locationManager = null;
    public LocationListener locationListener = null;
    public Location location = null;

    public static GpsListener getInstance(){
        if(refrence == null){
            refrence = new GpsListener();
        }
        return refrence;
    }

    public void startGpsCallBack(Context activityContext){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) activityContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new mylocationlistener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            ConfigClass.latitudeValue = location.getLatitude();
            ConfigClass.longitudeValue = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    public class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                ConfigClass.latitudeValue = location.getLatitude();
                ConfigClass.longitudeValue = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    public void stopGpsCallBack(){
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
    }

    public void startGpsCallbackAgain(Context activityContext){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) activityContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new mylocationlistener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        location = locationManager
        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            ConfigClass.latitudeValue = location.getLatitude();
            ConfigClass.longitudeValue = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code

First `startGpsCallBack`, then `stop` it and then call `startGPSCallBackAgain` method
Check it and let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: i want to use the GPS_PROVIDER value. please i hove can i use gps. and why it return null value.

Comment: GPS provide will never give you location untill the gps symbol on the notification bar is stable. So you have to first calculate last know location through network provider and then get the current location via GPS( It takes time)

Comment: please upload to me if you have an example.

Comment: @whiteLT Welcome my friend

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for current location:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10,
                    10, mlocListener);


public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                     VisualCV.this);
                dlgAlert.setMessage("Gps Disabled ");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Message");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                dlgAlert.create().show();

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Latitud = loc.getLatitude();
            longtitude = loc.getLongitude();
            lang = String.format("%.4f", longtitude);//LONGITUDE

            lati = String.format("%.4f", Latitud);//LATITUDE




        }
    }
```

Comment: i want to use GPS_PROVIDER not a NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: you want current location or what??

Comment: i want current location but through GPS_PROVIDER

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
              LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

              LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
              mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

            }

            /* Class My Location Listener */
            public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
            {

              public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
              {
                loc.getLatitude();
                loc.getLongitude();

                String Text = "My current location is: " +
                "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
                "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

              public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
              {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
              }

              public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
              {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

              public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
              {

              }
            }
```